# Is it possible to disable header on HTTP redirect?

Tags: http, http-headers

1. Client app sends a request with `Authorization` header to the server
2. Server checks authorization and responds with redirect (302) to azure storage
3. The browser goes to azure with the original authorization header
4. azure doesn't like this header + we don't want the original header to be redirected for security reasons

Is there a way to disable header redirect?

Comment: If the two domains are different and the client is sending the same Authorization header, then I would assume that the client has a bug.